# run remote commands between pods

Tags: kubernetes, containers, monitoring, kubernetes-pod

I've a question.

How can I run a netstat command in a pod A from a pod B?, pod A and B are in a different namespace. My pod A stablish connection with a server outside the cluster and my pod B contains a script that convert netstat result in SNMP traps. I can't modify pod A image to include anything. Pod B it's from my own.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no network policies in place then something like this should work :

```
kubectl exec -it <pod B> -- sh
> ssh user@podA.podAnamespace "your command"
```

Note that `ssh` must be installed on the podB and you must have a user to connect with on Pod A.

Comment: sorry, I omitted that, I don't have user in pod A, it is a third party application.